# How to speed up the mongo query for getting the min and max values in range?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, indexing

I have a simple collection that contains two fields: timestamp and value (float). I need to get min and max values in the timestamp range.

The collection contains approx 10000000 documents.

I've add indexes like
`{"value" : 1, "timestamp" : 1}` and `{"value" : -1, "timestamp" : 1}`.

Queries like

`db.getCollection('Sample').find({'timestamp' : {'$gte': 1714284644, '$lte': 1745820644}}).sort({'value':-1}).limit(1)`

took about 1 second. Count without limit shows 525600 documents.

"Explain" show that query covered by one of the indexes. IXSCAN takes most of the time.

Is there any way to speed this query up?

Comment: Did you try index { "timestamp" : 1} or { "timestamp" : 1, value: - 1}?

Comment: Maybe consider bucketing: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern

Comment: I've tried to use the following indexes and their combinations:  { "timestamp" : 1} , { value: - 1, "timestamp" : 1},  { value: 1, "timestamp" : 1}, { value: 2, "timestamp" : 1}.